# Method taking two default parameters

Tags: c++

I have a method with the following definition:

```
void foo(int i = 0, bool flag = false) {}
```

I want to call foo() by passing only the second argument:

```
foo(true);
```

But like this it will always pass it to the first parameter (i).
Is there any other solution I can pass my argument to the second parameter ? Or the only way is to pass the first one also.

```
foo(0, true);
```

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/77-default-parameters/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically no.  But you can fake it with overloads, thusly:

```
void foo(bool flag)
{
    foo(0,flag);
}
```

Comment: @amit: No. Read about function overloading.

Comment: sorry, was mistaken with the case of foo(bool,int)

Comment: This is good, but number of overloads required grows exponentially with the number of parameters.

Answer (score 2):

no. unlike python, you cannot explicitly state which parameter you want to have the value. you will have to call the method with all the parameters if you need the last one to be not the default.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible in C++, since it doesn't support named parameters: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.20

However you may use overloading:

```
void foo(int i, bool flag) {
    //do stuff
}
inline void foo(int i) { foo(i, false); }
inline void foo(bool flag) { foo(0, flag); }


int main(void) {
    foo(42);
    foo(true);
    return 0;
}
```

The former would include the base implementation and gets called by the latter ones.

Notice how they're [inline](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html).

Comment: You cannot overload `void foo(int i)`

Comment: @Nawaz: you can. You have to jump through hoops to call it, but you can declare and define the overload.

Comment: @Nawaz: that call is ambiguous, but you can have the overload: http://www.ideone.com/nS9Nk. Compiles just fine. Both functions are there, and both are callable. You just need to work around the ambiguity: http://www.ideone.com/rrO3M

Comment: @Nawaz: [Don't mix](http://www.ideone.com/Bmzgh) this overloading approach with the default-param approach.

Answer (score 1):

No, when you want to pass only one parameter, you will pass the first. How the compiler could guess which parameter do you intend to use?

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice "trick" called the named parameter idiom : http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.20

Here's a rough way you'd implement it for your code.
(Though its really only useful for cases where there's a lot more default/optional arguments)

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    //set the defaults
    Foo():i_(100),flag_(false) {}
    //provide the mutators
    Foo& i(int in_i) { i_ = in_i; return *this; }
    Foo& flag(int in_flag) { flag_ = in_flag; return *this; }
    void operator() { foo( arg.i_, arg.flag_ ); } //Just forward to the full argument version
  protected:
    int i_;
    bool flag_;
};
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
Foo()(); // First () creates temporary, second calls its operator()
Foo().i(20)();
Foo().flag(false)();
Foo().i(10).flag(false)();
```

There's some variants on this trick that you can use. You can put the arguments into a struct with mutators, but write a `void foo(FooArgs)` function. In this case you end up with something like:

```
foo( FooArgs().i(10) );
```

You can also call `foo` from from the `Foo` destructor rather than `operator()`. In that case your calls look like this:

```
Foo().i(20); // foo called when this temporary destructs
```